# Set of discontinuities of one function is smaller than that of another

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let's say I know that the set of discontinuities of a function $f$, denoted by $D_f$, has measure zero (although I don't believe that fact matters). I think that it follows that the set of discontinuities of $\left|f\right|^{1/2}$ must be smaller than $D_f$, and hence must also have measure zero. I can't see rigorously why this is true. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is continuos at $x$, then $|f|^{1/2}$ is also continuous a $x$. The set of continuity points of $f$ is contained in the set of continuity points of $|f|^{1/2}$.